# Reprojecting Euclidean distance in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to develop a pipeline for predicting future locations of deforestation using Earth Engine. One of the variables in the model is distance from previous deforestation locations.

I can easily create the layer using the euclidean distance algorithm, but when I try to sample it using stratifiedSample, it returns this error:
[image]

I think I have narrowed the problem down to something to do with the scale of the Euclidean distance layer, as when I exclude the layer, it easily samples my other input layers.

I have checked the distance layers projection and its the same EPSG: 4326 as the other layers, the difference seems to be the scale, which according to `print(euclideanDist.select('distance').projection().nominalScale())` is  111319.49079327357
whereas all my other layers are 27.829872698318393.

I have tried to resample the Euclidean distance layer to the same scale, using `.resample()` and `.reproject()` but that results in a highly transparent layer with a lot of lost information. I am wondering if the issue is that EarthEngine is storing the scale of the data incorrectly which is why I am experiencing these problems?

Here is my code if you wish to recreate the problem.

```
// this is an excerpt from my code to recreate the problems I am having with reproject and resampling of the euclidean distance data in relation to the ML pipeline I am developing.

//Set the project Area
var AOI = ee.FeatureCollection('users/theonlyhayden/Lunga_luswishi_Project_area');

//Import forest loss data
var forest = ee.Image("UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2021_v1_9").clip(AOI);

//Define the projection and scale
var proj = forest.projection();
var crs = proj.crs();
var scale = proj.nominalScale();

//Add additional layers
var treeCover = forest.select('treecover2000');
var biomass = ee.Image('WHRC/biomass/tropical').select('Mg').clip(AOI);
var DEM = ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003').clip(AOI);
var DEM = DEM.resample('bilinear').reproject({crs:crs, scale:scale}).select('elevation');
var slope = ee.Terrain.slope(DEM);
var aspect = ee.Terrain.aspect(DEM);
var lossyear = forest.select('lossyear');
var loss = ee.Image(1)
      .where(lossyear.eq(0), 1)
      .where(lossyear.gte(1).and(lossyear.lte(22)), 2);
var lossyear = forest.select('lossyear');
var label = 'loss'
var loss = loss.clip(AOI).rename(label).toByte();

//Calculate the distance from deforested areas
var targetImg = ee.Image(0)
      .where(lossyear.eq(0), 0)
      .where(lossyear.gte(1).and(lossyear.lte(22)), 1);
var maxDistM = 10000;  // 10 km

var euclideanKernel = ee.Kernel.euclidean(maxDistM, 'meters');
var euclideanDist = targetImg.distance(euclideanKernel).rename('distance').clip(AOI);

var euclideanKernel = ee.Kernel.euclidean(maxDistM, 'meters');
var euclideanDist = targetImg.distance(euclideanKernel).rename('distance').clip(AOI);

//Try and resample to the same scale as the other datasets
var euclideanDist_resampled = euclideanDist.resample().reproject({crs:crs, scale:scale}).clip(AOI)

print(euclideanDist.select('distance').projection().nominalScale());
print(euclideanDist_resampled.select('distance').projection().nominalScale()); // looks correct

//Set the viz. params.
var vis = {min: 0, max:maxDistM};

//Add the layers
Map.centerObject(AOI,9);
Map.addLayer(euclideanDist, vis, 'Euclidean distance'); // the way it should look, but the scale is wrong
Map.addLayer(euclideanDist_resampled, vis, 'Euclidean distance resampled'); // the way it looks after changing scale.

//test1 - This works - gathering training data without the inclusion of the Euclidean distance layer
var test1 = ee.Image([loss,treeCover,slope,aspect,DEM,biomass]);
var sample1 = test1.stratifiedSample({
  numPoints: 100,
  classBand: label,
  region: AOI,
  scale: scale,
  geometries: true
});
print(sample1);

//test2 - this doesnt work - gather training data with the inclusion of the Euclidean distance layer at original scale
var test2 = ee.Image([loss,treeCover,slope,aspect,DEM,biomass, euclideanDist]);
var sample2 = test2.stratifiedSample({
  numPoints: 100,
  classBand: label,
  region: AOI,
  scale: scale,
  geometries: true
});
print(sample2); // Does not work

//test3 - this does not work - gather training data with the inclusion of the Euclidean distance layer after reprojection
var test3 = ee.Image([loss,treeCover,slope,aspect,DEM,biomass, euclideanDist_resampled]);
var sample3 = test2.stratifiedSample({
  numPoints: 100,
  classBand: label,
  region: AOI,
  scale: scale,
  geometries: true
});
print(sample3); // Does not work
```